# EditText hint not showing (Java - android)

Tags: android, android-edittext, hint

I saw lots of questions about this topic, but I've found anything that solve my problem.
I saw different solutions:

- Removing gravity

  Removing inputType

  Insert android:ellipsize attribute

But no one has worked.
Here's a sample of my code:

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/edtNotesText"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_below="@+id/layoutNotesEditMenu"
    android:gravity="left|top"
    android:hint="@string/edt_text_notes_add_hint"
    android:inputType="textFilter|textMultiLine|textNoSuggestions"
    android:padding="6dp"
    android:scrollbars="vertical"
    android:textColor="@color/lightGrey"
    android:textSize="20sp" />
```

Comment: try setting  
using android:ellipsize="end"

Comment: As I wrote in the question, this don't work. I tried again right now, and no way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've find out the problem: I forgot the instruction "setContentView"! Might be trivial but maybe could help someone else.

Comment: Can you explain more ?

Comment: Unfortunately, after two years, I can't remember the problem: maybe I forgot to put setContentView somewhere, but I cannot be more specific. I'm sorry

Answer (score 4):

try changing your edit text's color and set proper gravity

```
android:textColorHint="#FFFFFF"
android:gravity="center"
android:ellipsize="end"
```

this is worth a try...

Comment: I tried once again, adding the rows you wrote, but again it doesn't work.

Comment: I'm getting mad because of this weird bug!

Comment: here's an alternate solution to this, try setting the string you want to edittext in oncreate...and when the edittext receives the focus clear the text

Comment: I was thinking about this solution, but doesn't fits my case because this prevents user from editing what they have written before, unless he will get removed his text everytime. Should I maybe try to put a global boolean that checks the first time that the EditText get touched?

Comment: there are thousand ways here to get your task done its upto you what you choose...

Comment: give a try and if it solves your problem don't hesitate to put it here so you can help the people here facing similar kind of problem...if you find this helpful you can upvote this

Answer (score 0):

None of those that you mentioned worked for me either, until I looked into my `.java` class file code. I had this:

```
   poemTitle.setText(poemListItem.getTitle());
   poemText.setText(poemListItem.getPoem());
```

As soon as I commented those out, then my hint text showed in both of my `EditText`s. I had this code there to draw upon a model class to get text, but actually don't need it since my app's users will edit their own text.